# How to add liferay document library print function

Tags: printing, liferay, document

My question is how to add liferay document library print function which prints the document itself. I know it should be a hook .. its clear but how ? I searched in internet but do not found anything. At all this portlet there is no such function in my opinion. Do u have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Before "the portlet" can print any document, it has to display its content. There's a preview of the content, rendered more or less correctly, but not at all sufficient as a full print resolution document. Liferay is running server-side, the frontend is a browser. Anything that your browser can display (i.e. HTML), your browser can print. Because, typically, it's rather your browser that's physically close to the printer you want to use. The server that Liferay is running on might be on a different continent.

Liferay can help you convert Office Documents (doc, odt, pdf, xls etc) into other formats, but it can't help you print documents. You can open the documents in whatever program you have installed client side. If you have no program that can open doc files (or any of the conversions), Liferay can't even make you see it on the screen - let alone print it.

Plus, no webserver in this world has direct access to your printer to send documents there. Whatever your underlying problem is: You'll have to solve it in a different way.